# Adding animation into ajax

Tags: json, jquery, animation

I wrote code in which .getJSON api from jquery is used to fetch images from flickr public api. Please see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ch4v3/). I have made each of the images to slide after each request gets finished. Now, I want the first set of image to slide downward  and then following sets to slide up first and then replaced by images from ajax request maintaining the same animation as used for the first set of images. I think a very little modification is enough. I thank you for your comment and suggestion before hand.

Comment: Are you asking how to rotate the images? Or did I misread?

Comment: I think what you're asking is, to show the first set of the request, and for the following request, the previous set slides down and then a new set is inserted... am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kDaJS/2/) what you had in mind?

```
getFlickr();
setInterval(getFlickr, 20000);

function getFlickr() {
    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', {
        'format': 'json'
    }, function(data) {
        if ($('p').length < 1) {
            addPiecePiece('#main',true,null);
        }
        else {
            $('.flickr').each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay(4000*i).slideUp(2000,function(){
                      addPiecePiece($(this),false,i);
                      $(this).remove();
                });
            });


        }

        function addPiecePiece(element,aoa,index) {
            $.each(data.items, function(key, value) {
                if(index == null || index == key){
                   title = value.title;
                   description = value.description;
                   photo = value.media.m;
                   html = $('<p class="flickr"></p>').html(description).css({
                       'display': 'none'
                   });

                   if(aoa == true){
                    $(html).appendTo(element).slideDown(2000);   
                   }else{
                    $(html).insertAfter(element).slideDown(2000);   
                   }
                }

            });
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. Each of the second set of image replace the existing image one by one. So, for replacing this image each of the existing one slides up, and then a new image comes into its place and then slides down and it goes on for all of the rest images.

Comment: Ahh... Got it. I'll take a look when I get back to a computer, if it's not answered already.

Comment: @insane-36 - I've updated the answer, the fiddle is updated as well. I think that's what you wanted. You can obviously play with the delay's and slideup and down times to better suit your needs. Hope it helps!